# Использование Memcache и Mysql вместе

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, асинхронность, memcached

Использую модули `mysql2` и `memcached`

Хочу делать запросы в бд если нужное не найдено в Memcache, но так как запросы асинхронные приходится использовать callback для mysql, но тогда код внутри не выполнится если запрос не будет произведен. То есть получается подобная конструкция (упрощено и без условий на наличие):

```
memcached.getMulti(['processed_msg'], function (err, data) {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ? ', [Id], function (error, results, fields) {
    ...код обработки
   });
});
```

Думаю смысл понятен. Как переделать так чтоб реализовать задуманное?

Comment: опишите отдельно функцию, использующую значение `var X = function(err, data) { ... }` внутри getMulti соответственно `if(data) X(err, data) else connection.query(...., ... {X(error, data)};)`

Comment: Я думал на счёт  этого,  но как я понимаю альтернативы нету?

Comment: Думаю можно еще посмотреть в сторону promise и await. Вроде они есть в node

Comment: Да есть,  вот только вроде выходит та же шляпа, могли бы подать пример для использования в данной ситуации

Comment: заворачиваете все  async функцию. внутри уже `memcached... function(err, data) { if(! data) await connection.query(...., function(e, res, f) { data=results ... });` Если я правильно понимаю, в следующую за if и query строку управление попадет когда БД уже вернула результат и он в data

Comment: Хмм,  по идее в случае с промисами результат с await можно записать даже так  let mydata = await  myasyncfunc(); Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться чем-то вроде [asyncjs/compose](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#compose) (или другими утилитами из нее) или [написать свою аналогичную функцию](https://youtu.be/z8Hg6zgi3yQ)

```js
import compose from 'async/compose';

const Id = 111

function getCache(keys, callback) {
  memcached.getMulti(perv, function(error, data) {
    callback(error, data)
  })
}

function getFromDB(data, callback) {
  if (data) return callback(null, data)
  
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id = ? ', [Id], function(error, [results]) {
    callback(error, results)
  });
}

const getData = async.compose(getCache, getFromDB);

getData(['processed_msg'], function(err, result) {
  // код обработки
});
```